# Why I can't send email using my domain local but if I'm using gmail it will successfully send in localhost

Tags: php, email

Why I can't send email using my domain in localhost? But when I used gmail smtp it's successfully sent email (in localhost)

This is the error using debug=4 :

```
2016-08-31 07:08:05 Connection: opening to ssl://mail.mydomain.com:443, timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2016-08-31 07:08:05  Connection: opened
```

this is my code

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                   // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.mydomain.mncgroup.com';                    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'emailsender@mydomain.com';         // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'pass';                   // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                         // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 443;  
$mail->SMTPDebug=4;

$mail->setFrom('emailsender@mydomain.com', 'a');
$mail->addReplyTo('emailsender@mydomain.com', 'a');

$mail->addAddress('myemail.mydomain.com');   // Add a recipient
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML



$mail->Subject = 'Reminder ';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;

} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: What does `echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;` print out on failure?

Comment: @jedifans nothing

Comment: Do you have set up SMTP server on `mail.mydomain.com:443`? If not, than requesting SMTP provider will fail

Comment: hmm i think it already set up, because in desktop application it can send email

Answer (score 0):

There is a lesser probability of sending mails from localhost as it requires SMTP server, and that is not installed by default. So you cannot send mails from local directly.
There are solutions :

1. Install the SMTP server on your local.
2. Use third party SMTP server. (You are using GMAIL)

In case you go by second solution, Please go through the below link

http://www.mittalpatel.co.in/php_send_mail_from_localhost_using_gmail_smtp